# SVG <image> modify fill in external svg file

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

Is it possible modify "fill" when svg is image?

> index.html

```
<svg width="500" height="400" id="svg">
    <image xlink:href="file.svg" />
</svg>
```

> file.svg

```
<svg>
<g>
    <rect id="first" x="0" y="0" fill="black" width="36" height="50"/>
    <rect id="second" x="20" y="20" fill="blue" width="36" height="56"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: no, I don't think so... but, I've been wrong many times before

Comment: No it's not possible. https://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/